# Why when I submit the form the variable loses the value on PHP

Tags: php

I need to find the average age of x people. But when I submit the form the variable $cont loses the value. I know that every time I submit the form the page is reloaded and the variable $cont takes the value of 0 again. But I don't know how to keep the addition on that variable and I need another one that counts the people that submit the form to finally make the average. This is what I got so far:

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['btn'])) {
    $cont = 0;
    $edad = $_POST['ed'];
    $cont = $cont + $edad;
    echo "$cont";
}


?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" > 
    <title>Encuesta</title>
</head>

<body>

    <form action="encuesta.php" method="post">

        <table>

            <tr>
                <td><input type="text" placeholder="Nombre" name="nom"></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td><input type="text" placeholder="Apellido" name="ape">    </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td><input type="text" placeholder="Edad" name="ed"></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td><input type="text" placeholder="Dirección" name="dir"></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td><input type="text" placeholder="Barrio" name="bar"></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td><input type="text" placeholder="Teléfono" name="tel"></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td align="center"><input type="submit" value="Procesar" name="btn"></td>
            </tr>

        </table>

    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you can use $_SESSION to store the cont data, if the form is submitted from the same connection. If you need to calculate the data from different connections, you need to store the data somewhere like database

Comment: [The HTML5 placeholder attribute is not a substitute for the label element](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201204/the_html5_placeholder_attribute_is_not_a_substitute_for_the_label_element/)

Answer (score 2):

You need to replace `$cont = 0;` with some code which takes a value from somewhere that has a lifetime beyond a single execution of your PHP program (you'll also need to store the new value in that place).

Since you want to count different people, that can't be anything tied to the browser, so you should look at storing it on your server. For example, in a database.